# Data tidying help: splitting one column with all the data

Tags: r

I am in need of some help with data tidying. I downloaded my conversation with someone on Facebook messenger, but it's output is something as followed:

```
V1.  
Person A  
Coolcool  
2018-06-25 19:34  
Person B  
See you later  
:D  
2018-06-25 19:34  
Person A  
You called Person B   
Duration: 30 seconds   
2018-06-25 19:19  
Person B.  
What's up?   
2018-06-25 19:09  
Person A   
Hey!   
2018-06-25 19:09
```

They're all in one column, but I'm trying to make a data frame where the speaker is in one column, the message is in another, and the date would be in another. The problem that I'm facing is that, sometimes, the message is in two rows, so I can't just split the whole column into three columns. What would be the best solution to this? Appreciate any help with this :)

Comment: Is the order of the lines always the same? So a message always begins with the user's name and ends with the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Since your entries are always "Person A" (or Person B) and ends by a date, format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM, I would use regex like this :

```
library(stringr)
date_match="\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}"
col_a=str_match_all(chat_messenger,
                    paste0("(?<=\n|^)Person A\\s*\n([\\s\\S]*?)\n",date_match, sep="")
                    )[[1]][,2]
col_b=str_match_all(chat_messenger,
                    paste0("(?<=\n)Person B\\s*\n([\\s\\S]*?)\n",date_match, sep="")
)[[1]][,2]
col_a
col_b
```

Which gives as results :

```
> col_a
[1] "Coolcool  "                                      "You called Person B   \nDuration: 30 seconds   "
[3] "Hey!   "                                        
> col_b
[1] "See you later  \n:D  " ".  \nWhat's up?   "
```

---

For a better understanding of the regex matching :
I will divide this line :
    (?<=\n|^)Person A\s*\n([\s\S]*?)\n

- `(?<=\n|^)` is looking for something that is preceded by a line space, or the beginning of the document in case you would use the words "Person A" in your chat.
- `Person A\\s*\n` : looks for the name followed by space (at least 0) and a linebreak
- `([\\s\\S]*?)` : Extract everything including linebreaks
- `\n` : Stop the extraction before linebreak